# What values of k are the two matrices row equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra

Considering the following two matrices I am trying to find for what values of k are the two matrices row equivalent. The hint I received is "if we row reduce B to make a zero row, we can more easily see the value of k".

$$
A = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix} \hspace{1.0cm}
B = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 2 & 4 \\
    2 & k & 6 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

For matrix B I started by dividing row 2 elements by 2 and row 3 elements by 3 to get the following:
$$
B = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 \\
    1 & k & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Then, I made row 3 equal to subtracting row 1 from row 3 to produce the following:
$$
B = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & k-1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

And so B is inconsistent for k = 1 if the resulting is not equal to 0 but consistent if it is. For example, 0 + 0 + 0 = 0 is fine but 0 + 0 + 0 = 7 is not.

How do I go about finding the values for k that make the two matrices row equivalent? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you divided $R_3$ by $2$ you didn't divide $k$ so you reduction is wrong.

Reducing $B$ you obtain :
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 2 & 4 \\
    2 & k & 6 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\to
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & k-2 & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

So $  A \sim {B}$ for $k=2$. No other value is possible because when  $k \neq 2$ the third row isn't reducible to $(0,0,0)$ using any elementary operation.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. How did you get k - 2? Trying to follow how you got there  so I can understand. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind. I figured out how you got k - 2. Thank you for the feedback.